# CSS rotate text - complicated

Tags: jquery, css, transform

This is just a CSS issue, but could be saved with jQuery perhaps or very clever CSS techniques. See what you think. I've created a JSFiddle so you can experiment. http://jsfiddle.net/WMVMW/157/

See problem below.

This only has to work on android and safari browsers - so don't worry about IE!

When I started this project, I originally planned to use CSS3 to rotate some html text - not really fully understanding the implications of transform property.

The idea of what I am doing is an interactive floor plan. I am having lots of absolute positioned DIVS which represent booths/stands. Because some of my DIVS are really thin but high, my idea was to rotate the text inside the DIV -90 degrees.

This is how each DIV is layed out - They're not actually DIV's but A tags with DIV style behaviors.

```
<a href="" title="" id="200" class="cell"><span>Harley Davidson</span></a>
```

The span inside of the A tag has `display: table cell;` behavior, this is so the text can be vertically aligned inside the box.

The ID number on the A tag only does position styles, the class `.cell` style controls all other behaviors..

My challenge is to introduce a new class called `.rotate` which rotates the text -90degrees. But still having the same appearance in looks - and the text flows instead of inheriting the width and height from the containing A tag. See below how the rotate class is added...

```
<a href="" title="" id="200" class="cell rotate"><span>Harley Davidson</span></a>
```

See the JSfiddle here... with all css styles, and the

http://jsfiddle.net/WMVMW/157/

Any help would be awesome. I hope this is understandable enough.

Comment: Are you trying to do like this: http://jsfiddle.net/rathoreahsan/gjQfY/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The trick is to rotate the whole `a` and not just the `span`. Live example: http://jsfiddle.net/WMVMW/164/

```
a.rotate{
    -moz-transform:rotate(-90deg);
    -webkit-transform:rotate(-90deg);
    -o-transform:rotate(-90deg);
    -ms-transform:rotate(-90deg);   
}

#R135, #R135-1 {
    left: -35px;
    top: 85px;
    width:157px;
    height: 42px;    
}
```

So I reversed the `width` and `height` (as it is going to be rotated) and then repositioned it.

Comment: I think this is the only way it can be done. Unless clever javascript is used to flip the inherited heights of the span. I was avoiding this option because I have alot of stands to reposition and reverse width/heights. ...but this seems so far the only feasible way. Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0):

You could add an extra `<span>` inside the other: http://jsfiddle.net/WMVMW/160/

Comment: This does not show all of the text. It cuts off the word *retail* from *Harley Davidson Retail*.

Comment: This is what I first tried, but the 'harley davidson retail' text is braking onto three lines - needs to flow on one line.

The inherited width and height values of the span somehow need to be flipped - then it would work! - probably even with out an extra span. Thanks  for you help.