# How to rotate -90 the cell in a correctly way?

Tags: html, asp.net, css

I'm trying to rotate a text (-90 degree to a header columns from a cell). I'm utilizing the following code: [CSS rotate text - complicated](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6995645/css-rotate-text-complicated)

This is the result:

[image]
http://contoso2.azurewebsites.net/Scores/ListScores

As you can see, when I rotate does not redimentionate and also I would like that all the text should be in the same line, (EXAMENES CON FORMATO 1 should be just one line, not two) and it's a little bit out of margin I guess.

What am I missing to produce the right way?

Answer (score 0):

To fix the wrapping problem, use `white-space:nowrap`

To get rotated text with element "resizing", use `writing-mode:tb-lr` - this will result in the text reading from top to bottom, so optionally add `transform:rotate(180deg)` to have it go from bottom to top instead.