# JavaScript CSS rotate text direction

Tags: javascript, css

This might sound simple but believe you me I have searched high and low without results.

I have created dynamic text in JavaScript as follows:

```
    context.fillText('name', 10, 10, 20);
```

I now need to have this text in a vertical orientation. 
NOTE: This text appears in a canvas that has other objects which I do not intend to rotate, so rotating the canvas is not the solution I am looking for.

I will be happy with a solution that uses css - reason being I may want to apply this angle and color attributes to several text on the canvas. I am new to using css so I can't figure out how to create it, identify this text to apply it to in-line in JavaScript.

Something like this: [CSS rotate text - complicated](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6995645/css-rotate-text-complicated), but this example has the text in html, so it has named tag to reference the text with. My text doesn't have a name tag (or can I add that?) so I am kind of stuck in there.

Comment: Have you considered using `save()` and `restore()`?

Comment: You can't apply CSS to text rendered in a canvas

Comment: Noted, gilly3. Your suggestion to achieve vertical orientation of the a desired text object while maintaining orientation of other objects (line, image, etc)?

Comment: tom, I am not as sophisticated as my question may suggest, but I think I have read a bit of that. Let me dig it up a bit more; but would be glad if you point me to some working sample, please. thanks. I have a feeling that is the direction I need to take.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `save()` and `restore()` to restrict the transformation to the text:

```
c = canvas.getContext("2d");
c.save(); // save the current styles and transformations
c.translate(20, 50); // move origin to (20, 50)
c.rotate(-Math.PI / 2); // rotate 90 degrees anticlockwise about origin
c.fillText("name", 0, 0); // draw the text vertically
c.restore(); // restore previous styles and transformations
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/chtJ2/

Comment: while I had figured out I could replace fillText with document.write procedure, it came with its own issues (jumbling up the text despite my best efforts to maintain spacing). This (tom's answer) is how I intended it from the beginning so I am glad you shared it.

Answer (score 0):

How about:

```
.fillText {
     -moz-transform: rotate(7.5deg);  
       -o-transform: rotate(7.5deg);  
  -webkit-transform: rotate(7.5deg);  
             filter:  progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.BasicImage(rotation=0.083); 
         -ms-filter: "progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.BasicImage(rotation=0.083)";
}
```

Comment: Michael, I have been thinking in those lines but doesnt seem to work. Your example works when the text is in html section and has that fillText id (i tried several). My text is created in code in JavaScript inside a function, so I am not sure how to apply the css to it. May be gilly3 above is right?