# Rotate Span text using jquery

Tags: html, css

i want to rotate span text using jquery.

```
<DIV id=container_vml_YAxisTitle_1>
<SPAN style="FONT-SIZE: 14px; FONT-FAMILY: Segoe UI; POSITION: absolute; ZOOM: 1; COLOR: #707070; LEFT: -64px; FILTER: alpha(opacity=100); TOP: 234px; VISIBILITY: visible">Sales Amount in millions(USD)
</SPAN>
</DIV>
```

i referred the below link for rotating the text but it's not working as expected.

[CSS rotate text - complicated](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6995645/css-rotate-text-complicated)

tried like below

```
<SPAN style="FONT-SIZE: 14px; -ms-transform:rotate(-90deg);   FONT-FAMILY: Segoe UI; POSITION: absolute; ZOOM: 1; COLOR: #707070; LEFT: -64px;  TOP: 234px; VISIBILITY: visible">Sales Amount in millions(USD)
</SPAN>
```

but not working in IE7 and IE8 browser working fine in other browsers.

i am using  IE7 and IE8  browser. using jquery 1.7.1.

Thanks,

Siva

Comment: possible duplicate of [Does CSS transform property works on block and inline-block level elements only?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14883250/does-css-transform-property-works-on-block-and-inline-block-level-elements-only)

Answer (score 2):

1) You have to use `:` not `=`

```
-ms-transform:rotate(-90deg)
```

2) You should have given it under **`style`** attribute

```
<span  style="-ms-transform:rotate(-90deg); position: absolute">SPAN</span>
```

3) [*`span` doesn't have layout*](http://www.satzansatz.de/cssd/onhavinglayout.html), so you have to add **`position: absolute`** or **`display: block`** to `span` tag

Check this [**Fiddle1**](http://jsfiddle.net/WMVMW/1967/) and here is your [**fiddle2**](http://jsfiddle.net/WMVMW/1968/)

**Updates:**
For older version of IE

```
filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.BasicImage(rotation=1);
```

Comment: thanks for your update.but its not working as expected in IE7 browse. working fine in other browsers.

Comment: @SivaRajini You have to use `filter` to support older version of IEs check this http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms532847%28v=vs.85%29.aspx

Answer (score 0):

This is css code - you should add this to `<style></style>` tag or `style` attribute:

```
<span style="-ms-transform:rotate(-90deg)"> </span>
```

Comment: thanks for your update.but its not working as expected in IE7 browse. working fine in other browsers. –